# 'file is encrypted or is not a database' error while opening the sqlite db

Tags: encryption, sqlite

I have a sqlite database in my UWP app. On the very first launch of my app, I create the database and set it up with all the tables and stuff. I play around with the app and generate some data just fine. But when I close and relaunch the app, it starts giving me `'file is encrypted or is not a database'` error while trying to execute any query.
I am using sqlite3.dll v3.12.0 and here is my pragma key statement (with an example encryption key):

```
"PRAGMA key='aes256:66zk4rsKBIfSJ4vhF1XkzFxzrznOhjjnotuHRdKADIg='"
```

I verified, on second launch, the encryption key is being used to run the pragma key statement.

Edit: It looks like the encryption went just fine. Because, when I use a tool like [SQLite Manager](http://www.sqlabs.net/sqlitemanager.php/) and provide the same key, it opens the db just fine.

Comment: Hi Ashish, can you tell me the C# code you use to trigger the encryption of the DB with that PRAGMA key?

Answer (score 1):

I think what might be happening to you Is that you use to have a previous library of SQLite working with encryption working  properly like I did.

```
<SDKReference Include="SQLite.UAP.2015, Version=3.10.2">
  <Name>SQLite for Universal App Platform</Name>
</SDKReference>
```

And since you updated the library to v3.12.0 the PRAGMA key in this version did not work hence not being able to enter to the previous encrypted DB.

I'm trying to rebuild the link to that version but is hard: ["SQLite.UAP.2015, Version=3.10.2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311461/sqlite-uap-2015-version-3-10-2)

Comment: In my case I was encrypting the db with the same version i.e. v3.12.0 but still it was somehow giving error while decrypting it. However, the error was resolved when I reinstalled the sqlite package (not really sure how).

Comment: Hi Ashish, just to know, You are using the Universal Windows Platform Sqlite Extension right? http://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-uwp-3130000.vsix and the "SQLite.Net-PCL": "3.1.1",? regards.

Comment: Or Are you using SqlCipher?

Comment: I am using UWP Sqlite extension only.