# "SQLite.UAP.2015, Version=3.10.2"

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net

I need to find the "SQLite.UAP.2015, Version=3.10.2". as it had some features working that the current version does not as PRAGMA key.

I tried rebuilding the download link from:

```
http://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-uwp-3130000.vsix
```

as there is not any history in the webpage of previous dll's:

```
http://sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-uap-3102000.vsix
```

That does not work.How do I rebuild the link or Where can I find or can download the old Visual Studio Extension?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the link using the way back machine.
https://web.archive.org/web/20160202165309/http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Here's the direct link:

http://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-uap-3100200.vsix